# Count tag occurrences between two tags using PHP

Tags: php, count

How do I get the `<model>` tag count between `<make_1></make_1>` tags? The `<model>` tag can be any number of tags.

```
<make_1>
<model_1>product Name</model_1>
<model_2>product Name</model_2>
<model_3>product Name</model_3>
<model_4>product Name</model_4>
</make_1>
```

Comment: Thanks @chris85 that's exactly what I've been looking for. Nice.

Comment: @chris85 sounds silly but how do I move it to resolved?

Answer (score 2):

If I don't misunderstood your requirements then you can simply try like below. [php.net](http://php.net) has a super simple example for `count` element in parent tag. See the example here http://php.net/manual/en/simplexmlelement.count.php and I urge you to also see more about [SimpleXMLElement](http://php.net/manual/en/class.simplexmlelement.php)

```
$xml = <<<EOF
<make_1>
  <model_1>product Name</model_1>
  <model_2>product Name</model_2>
  <model_3>product Name</model_3>
  <model_4>product Name</model_4>
</make_1>
EOF;
$elem = new SimpleXMLElement($xml);

// THIS IS JUST FOR DEBUG PURPOSE
print '<pre>';
print_r($elem);
print '<pre>';
echo "Element Count: ". $elem->count();
```

**Output:** Element Count: 4

**DEMO:** https://eval.in/980182

Comment: Oh, `count` of `simplexml` is a good usage. Guess I havent looked at simplexml enough.

Answer (score 2):

You can make the string a [SimpleXML](http://php.net/manual/en/simplexmlelement.construct.php) object then just count it (assuming it is always one level).

```
$xml = new simplexmlelement('<make_1>
<model_1>product Name</model_1>
<model_2>product Name</model_2>
<model_3>product Name</model_3>
<model_4>product Name</model_4>
</make_1>');
echo count($xml);
```

Demo: https://3v4l.org/V5LO5

Answer (score 0):

Just an alternative solution:

```
<?php
$string='<make_1>
<model_1>product Name</model_1>
<model_2>product Name</model_2>
<model_3>product Name</model_3>
<model_4>product Name</model_4>
</make_1>';

echo preg_match_all("/(<model_[^>]+\>)/i", $string, $matches);
```

OUTPUT:

```
4
```

Source: http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match-all.php

DEMO: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/56fb35a317e81bd3bc6d79abec720d1ab09063d1